# How to open the "Run Application" dialog from a terminal?

Tags: gnome, command-line

How can I open a dialog box as below from a terminal?

[image: Screenshot: "Run Application" dialog box]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the X11 keyboard/mouse input simulator `xdotool` and run `xdotool key Alt+F2`.

You can add this alias to your `~/.bashrc` file to make typing easier:

```
alias rd="xdotool key Alt+F2"
```

Now all you need to do is type `rd`.

Hacky, but works.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Install gmrun from Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install gmrun` then use command `gmrun` from the terminal
2. Compile gnome-run from source and run `gnome-run` from the terminal. Instructions [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110825023328/http://bioinfo.cipf.es/dbau/gnome_run.html). [*Editor's note: instruction page contains dead links.*]

Unfortunately this is harder than it should be.

Answer (score 3):

In case of Mate Desktop use

```
mate-panel --run-dialog
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do it:

1. Install the
   [xautomation](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xautomation) [image: Install xautomation] package
2. Run this command: `xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F2' 'keyup Alt_L'`

Thanks [htorque](https://askubuntu.com/users/3037/htorque) for the hint ["keyboard/mouse input"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49149/how-to-open-the-run-application-dialog-from-a-terminal/49155#49155)

Answer (score 2):

For LXDE/Lubuntu/LightDM, run `lxpanelctl run` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
gnome-panel-control --run-dialog
```

Comment: You need to install `gnome-panel-control` to tun this command.

Answer (score 1):

```
bash -c "$(zenity --entry --title 'Enter a Command' --text '' --width 400)"
```

Comment: That will result in an error if the dialogue is cancelled. It would be better to capture the output of `zenity` and only proceed if it returned successfully: `cmd="$(zenity --entry --title 'Enter a Command' --text '' --width 400)" && bash -c "$cmd"` or even `zenity --entry --title 'Enter a Command' --text '' --width 400 | bash`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 the original command runs without error. Tested dialogue cancel, providing valid command, providing invalid command, and providing no command. Not sure why our systems are behaving differently.